# Python subprocess - command execution on remote machine via ssh without shell interpreting semicolon or ampersand

Tags: python, security, ssh, subprocess

I have a requirement to execute some commands via `ssh` on a remote host for which I have to use only `subprocess`.

For security concerns, I have whitelisted the commands that can be executed on the remote but arguments to those commands are user provided.

For ex: `ls` command will be whitelisted but `-l` argument to the command will come from user via API.

Currently my implementation will not stop a user to execute any arbitrary command on remote by using `;` or `&` in the user supplied arguments.

For example, a user can pass: `-l ; cat /etc/passwd` to the `ls` command which will be executed at remote.

Now I have added a function to check if there are any special characters in the user supplied input but this looks bit insecure because blacklisting only few characters may still leave a loophole.

Is there any other safer solution to this issue with the restriction that I can only use `subprocess` and user input cannot be restricted?

Please help.

My current code:

```
def executeCommand(cmd, log):
    try:
        resultobj = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True, universal_newlines=True)
        if not resultobj.stdout.strip() == '':
            log.info("Command output: %s", resultobj.stdout)
            return resultobj.returncode, resultobj.stdout
        log.error("Command Execution returned None: %s", cmd)
        return -1, resultobj.stdout + "\n" + resultobj.stderr
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        log.error("Command Execution Failed for Command: %s with error %s", cmd, e.stderr)
        return e.returncode, e.stderr
    except subprocess.SubprocessError as e:
        log.error("Command Execution Failed for Command: %s with error %s", cmd, traceback.format_exc())
        return -1, traceback.format_exc()
```

Command passed to above function will look like:

```
ssh_cmd = ['ssh', '-oConnectTimeout=10', '-oBatchMode=yes', '-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-q', '1.1.1.1', 'ls -l ; cat /etc/passwd']

retcode, cmd_result = executeCommand(ssh_cmd, log)
```

The special character blacklist function pasted below:

```
def isBlacklistedChar(str):

    filter_chars = "&;|"
    if any(c in filter_chars for c in str):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: As a general principle, blacklisting the problems you have identified is less secure (more prone to mistakes or oversights) than enumerating the things you want to permit. As a quick observation, backticks and dollar signs are obvious leaks in your current implementation, but what to whitelist depends on what your use case is. Alphabetics, numbers, dashes, spaces...? Slashes? That could expose you to directory traversal bugs. Quotes? In the limit, implementing your own restricted shell might be less daunting than fencing all the features of a full shell.

Comment: Many Thanks @tripleee for your comment. I did realize that there isn't any full proof solution to this issue other than restricting the user input to a few acceptable characters. Now we will restrict the user input to only alphanumeric characters.